# Align Logo at center of Header

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center align my **`Logo`** of my screen but not able to accomplish. Please help.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Header Start -->
<div class="MastHead" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
<div class="HeaderLft"><a href="#dashboard" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse"><img alt="" title="" src="images/top_lft_arrow.png"  /></a></div>
<div class="HeaderRgt"><div class="TopRedBox"><a href="#" data-rel="back" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse" id=saveFav>Save</a></div></div>
<div class="HeaderLogo">LOGO</div>
</div>
 <!-- Header Ends -->
```

**CSS**

```
.HeaderLogo 
{
    position: absolute;
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 100px;
    top:10px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can do it with an absolute position bute why isn't it the descendant of the #MastHead?

Comment: Do you want the image to be centered or the whole bar?

Answer (score 2):

2 Possibilities:

```
   .HeaderLogo {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Or

**html**

```
<div class="HeaderLogoWrapper"><div class="HeaderLogo">LOGO</div></div>
```

**css**

```
.HeaderLogoWraper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One method to do this is to put all your `div` tags into another `div` with the class wrapper.
You can then add the CSS `text-align: center;` on your wrapper class and that will center align your header.

This is shown in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MTXba/). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A6CKL/)**

**css**

```
.HeaderLogo {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

---

**[demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/A6CKL/1/)**

```
.MastHead {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.HeaderLogo {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
}
.TopRedBox{
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        .HeaderLogo 
         { position: absolute; 
          margin:0px; auto; 
          width: 100%;
          text-align:center;
          }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Hacve/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center the image, you can do that with CSS property background-position:

```css
.MastHead {
 background-image: url('mylogo.png);
 background-position: top;
}
```

Reference on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fbackground-position

It will not work in IE6 (not sure with IE7) if someone is still using them...

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you

Can you use **margin-left:** property instead of **margin**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .HeaderLogo
        {
          position: absolute;
          width: 100px;
          top:10px;
          margin-left:45%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="MastHead" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">

<div class="HeaderLft">
  <a href="#dashboard" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">
    <img alt="logo" title="" src="images/top_lft_arrow.png"  />
  </a>
</div>

<div class="HeaderRgt">
  <div class="TopRedBox">
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse" id=saveFav>
      Save
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="HeaderLogo">LOGO
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope this will work, and if it isn't working, then you can set **`position:relative`**

Answer (score 0):

Follow instruction here. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

`.className {
    margin: auto;
}`

This should work!