# How do I get header with centered logo

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my CSS code. I'm trying to make header with logo between nav links. Which is the best solution for this. The background of the header has to be the same like the hero section? I made it but the header position was relative and i want this works if the header is absolute

```css
.header:after { 
          font-size: 0; 
          position: relative; 
          content: ''; 
          display: table; 
          clear: both; 
        }
        
        .header .header__logo { 
          position: absolute; 
          top: 0; 
          left: 50%;  
          margin-left: -53px; 
          font-size: 0; 
          width: 100%; }
        
        .header .header__nav { 
          margin-top: 5px; 
        }
        
        .nav ul { 
          list-style-type: none; 
        }
        .nav ul:after { 
          content: ''; 
          display: table; 
          clear: both; 
        }
        
        .nav li { 
          display: inline-block; 
          float: none;  
          margin-right: 30px; 
        }
        
        .nav li:nth-child(1) { 
          float: left; 
        }
        .nav li:nth-child(2) { 
          float: left; 
        }
        .nav li:nth-child(3) { 
          float: left; 
        }
        .nav li:nth-child(4) { 
          float: right; 
        }
        .nav li:nth-child(5) { 
          float: right; 
        }
        .nav li:nth-child(6) { 
          float: right; 
        }
        .nav li:last-child { 
          margin-right: 0; 
        }
        
        .nav li a { 
          color: #7191aa; 
          font-size: 16px; 
          font-weight: 300; 
          line-height: 1.2; 
        }
        .nav li a:hover { 
          color: white; 
        }
        
        .logo { 
          display: inline-block; 
          width: 106px; 
          height: 106px; 
          background: url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat 0 0; 
        }
    .hero { 
      position: relative; 
      height: 850px; 
      background: url(../images/bg.png); 
    }
    
    .hero .hero__content { 
      text-align: center; 
    }
    
    .hero .hero__content p { 
      color: #243c4f; 
      line-height: 1.87; 
      margin-bottom: 45px; 
    }
```

```html
<header class="header">
            <div class="shell">
                <div class="header__logo">
                    <a href="#" class="logo"></a>
                </div> <!-- /.header__logo -->
    
               
                <div class="header__nav">
                    <nav class="nav">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Academics</a>
                            </li>
    
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Arts</a>
                            </li>
    
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Athletics</a>
                            </li>
    
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">About</a>
                            </li>
    
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Give</a>
                            </li>
    
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Admissions</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav> <!-- /.nav -->
                </div> <!-- /.header__nav -->
            </div> <!-- /.shell -->
        </header> <!-- /.header -->
    
        <section class="hero">
            <div class="shell">
                <div class="hero__content">
                    <h1>We Honor God with Excellence</h1>
    
                    <p>
                        We partner with parents to provide a premiere, Christ-centered, college preparatory experience for students in preschool through 12th grade.
                    </p>
    
                    <a href="#" class="btn">Plan a visit</a>
                </div> <!-- /.hero__content -->
            </div> <!-- /.shell -->
        </section> <!-- /.hero -->
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), or else we cannot help you.

Comment: I do not see a `hero` section anywhere in your post. Also, can you paste your code and show us what you are trying to do. Does this post help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692371/align-logo-at-center-of-header

Comment: I added my code